# What is the difference b/w primitive datatypes and derived datatypes in XML schema world?

Tags: xml, types, xsd

Can someone elaborate on this notion ?
I am a beginner and unable to find a decent article on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by looking at the complete [type system of XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#typesystem). The following picture shows almost the whole type system, except for `anySimpleType` (all types below are simple types), and arbitrary, user-defined complex types.

> [image]

Have a look at the types that are referred to as "primitive types":

> [image]

Now, what makes those types "primitive"? They are primitive in the sense that the objects they represent have very little (if nothing) in common, and they behave very differently. Another way of saying this is that the semantics of those primitive types have little overlap. It also follows from this fact that none of the primitive types can be explained by the definition of another primitive type. Additionally, the primitive types are the ones most desperately needed when XML should be typed (e.g. in XSLT 2.0).

Then, there are derived types:

> [image]

Derived types are called "derived" because they are derived from one specific primitive type. As you can see, only `string` and `decimal` have built-in derived types. For instance, `token` is derived from `string`, as is `normalizedString`.

Crucially, all types derived from `string` still qualify as `string`, each of them defines a certain subset of strings allowed by `string`. On the other hand, one could not find a common ancestor type for all of the primitive types - except for `anySimpleType`, which is a rather abstract type.

The reason for this distinction between primitive and derived types is that the type system of XML Schema is *modular*: there is a finite set of atomic building blocks (primitive types) on the basis of which everything else is built.

Finally, the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#datatype-dichotomies) itself puts it very nicely by saying:

```
[Definition:]  Primitive datatypes are those that are not defined in terms of other datatypes; they exist ab initio.
[Definition:]  Derived datatypes are those that are defined in terms of other datatypes.
```

> unable to find a decent article on this one.

There are many resources explaining this topic, among others: http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/relax-CHP-8-SECT-1.html, http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.